# canvas_geometry_birds change mousemove for click?

Tags: javascript, onclick, three.js

How or Where should i modify the hover interaction for a click interation on this example? i try to change mousemove to click, mouseup or mousedown but this doesn't make any successful click interaction. Can you, please give me a hint how to modify this? I suppose that this function has to have to do with it, but i'm having some difficult to find the solution.

```
 document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', this.documentMouseMoveHandler.bind(this), false );

documentMouseMoveHandler: function ( e ) {
    var boid,
        offset = this.offset,
        boids = this.boids,
        vector = new THREE.Vector3( e.clientX - offset.x - this.halfViewWidth, - e.clientY - offset.y + this.halfViewHeight, 0 );

    //TODO: the scalar is a projection scaling number that is deduced from trial & errors, will find the correct formular to convert projection later
    vector.multiplyScalar(0.83);

    //debug
    //this.cube.position = vector.clone();

    //trace(3, 'offset: ' + offset.x + 'x' + offset.y + ' - vector: ' + vector.x + 'x' + vector.y);

    for ( var i = 0, il = boids.length; i < il; i++ ) {
      boid = boids[ i ];
      vector.z = boid.position.z;
      boid.repulse( vector );
    }

  }
```

Comment: change `mousemove` to `mousedown`

Comment: i tried to change mousemove to click, mouseup or mousedown but this doesn't make any successful click interaction